# How to extract a substring from a warning message in shell

Tags: shell, makefile

From my makefile, I called a perl script that will return a message containing a filepath, filename, line number and error message. I only need the filepath and filename. My script prints out this message to stdout so it gets automatically displayed in the console.

In my makefile, how can I get the filepath and filename? I am open to using grep, sed or tee or whichever is the most appropriate to use.

My string is this:

```
Warning: <filepath>/<filename>: <line number> <some message>
```

e.g:

```
Warning temp/output/dir/report.txt: 545 problem with parsing blah blah blah.
```

So, I will need to get the "temp/output/dir/report.txt" part only. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think "in a makefile" makes any difference? Commands in a Makefile are executed by the shell. You filter that output just as you would on the command line. Better rephrase the question to remove the whole "Makefile" part. Personally, I'd go for `perlscript | sed "s@Warning \([^:]*\):.*@\1@"`

Comment: @chris yo: can you provide feedback on the provided solutions below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the shell's positional parameters and parameter expansion. Viz:

```
$ set -- $(echo Warning: temp/output/dir/report.txt: 545 problem ...)
echo $2
temp/output/dir/report.txt:
$ echo ${2%:}       # Remove colon at the right
temp/output/dir/report.txt
```

This is totally POSIXy and does not rely on any bashisms. In your case, you would use

```
$ set -- $(script); echo ${2%:}
```

Or possibly

```
$ set -- $(script 2>&1); echo ${2%:}
```

If the message to extract goes to stderr instead of stdout. All of these assume the message is the first line. If this assumption is false, grep for the 'Warning:' string and it should work.

Comment: `^` for a pure `POSIX` way. Didn't even know such a style existed! lesson learnt!

Comment: One confirmation though, the part `$(script 2>&1)` is/same as command substitution right?

Comment: @Inian Yes, `$(cmd)` is just like `\`cmd\``, except for better nesting, avoiding excessive quoting. The `2>&1` part redirects stderr to stdout.

Comment: if there are some characters after ":", does the echo ${2%:} also removes it?

Comment: @chrisyo No. The `${name%pattern}` contruct removes the shortest match of *pattern* from the right. But you can use a pattern with a wildcard to remove everything after the rightmost colon: `${2%:*}`.